# Difference between ISR of a RTOS vs General Purpose OS

Tags: operating-system, rtos, isr

I am learning about ISR but I can not find what is the difference bewteen an interrupt service routine of a RTOS vs a General Purpose OS. Can anyone please explain the differecne between them, if there is any?

Comment: What do you mean by "a normal OS"?

Comment: @kkrambo, by normal OS I mean any operating system like Windows, Linux etc.

Comment: @DineshMaurya : "General-purpose" or "desktop" OS is probably a better description that "normal".

Comment: @Clifford, Thanks for your suggestion. Changed the word "normal" to "general purpose" to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an RTOS, exiting the interrupt context normally causes the scheduler to run (the ISR will have an *interrupt epilogue* that does this) in order to determine the highest priority ready task (which may have changed if the ISR has signalled a task in any way).  In a GPOS (*General-purpose OS*) on the other hand task switching is normally performed on a time-slice basis so the scheduler runs only on the OS clock interrupt.

To put it another way in a GPOS, on completion of an ISR it normally returns to whichever task was interrupted, while in an RTOS it evaluates the task schedule and switches context to the highest priority task in the *ready* state.

Comment: Hmm.. do you have any examples of the GPOS where 'the scheduler runs only on the OS clock interrupt'?  Windows and Linux certainly do not fall into that category.

Comment: @Clifford, If I understand the points from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84107/are-time-interrupts-always-followed-by-a-scheduler-call?rq=1   correctly then, scheduler should be called while returning from ISR even in general-purpose OS.

Comment: @DineshMaurya the 'ISR', (ie. driver), code has the choice.  It can do a normal interrupt return, or request a scheduling run.  Maybe it has only filled a fraction of a large network buffer & so it just returns.  Later, on another interrupt, when more data has come in, it can signal a semaphore/event/whatever and, (call/jump/set/whatever), request that the OS perform a scheduling run when interrupt-state is exited so as to make a thread that was waiting for the data ready/running 'immediately'..  There is no need or desire to wait for any timer - performance would be very bad if it did.

Comment: @DineshMaurya : The answer was a general one; different OS's may vary.  The point is in an RTOS it is necessary to run the scheduler for real-time priority based pre-emptive scheduling.  The scheduling policies of a GPOS are less constrained.